# How to check if "afile.xlsm:2" is already open VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, if-statement

I am have built a search bar in an Excel Worksheet where the user clicks [search]; it will sort the designated table column based off some FormControl buttons, then open a NewWindow off the current workbook, select Sheet2 and search the designated column on Sheet2 as well. I am having trouble preventing this from happening again the next time someone searches w/o closing the second window manually. I Currently only need two active windows open at once. So I don't want Excel to open a third ActiveWindow and so on.

I am not too familiar with utilizing Functions. I have pasted my macro Sub and Function. I've tried different configurations/variations thinking I am missing something simple (Hopefully).

It appears to me my AlreadyOpen function is not right. I can't seem to get my first `IF...True` statement to work when afile.xlsm:2 is already open.

```
Function AlreadyOpen(sFname As String) As Boolean
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    'Dim sFname As String
    sFname = "afile.xlsm:2"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wkb = Workbooks(sFname)
    AlreadyOpen = Not wkb Is Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
End Function


Private Sub Search_cmd1_Click()
'PURPOSE: Filter Data on User-Determined Column & Text/Numerical value

Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim SearchString As String
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant

'Load Sheet into A Variable
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
  On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
  Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range 'Table

'Retrieve User's Search Input
  mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("SearchBox1").Object.Text & "*"     'ActiveX Control    ''must include "*" for partials

'Determine if user is searching for number or text
  If IsNumeric(mySearch) = True Then
    SearchString = "=" & mySearch
  Else
    SearchString = "=*" & mySearch & "*"
  End If

'Loop Through Option Buttons
  For Each myButton In sht.OptionButtons
    If myButton.Value = 1 Then
      ButtonName = myButton.Text
      Exit For
    End If
  Next myButton

'Determine Filter Field
  On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
    myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Filter Data
      DataRange.AutoFilter _
        Field:=myField, _
        Criteria1:=SearchString, _
        Operator:=xlAnd

    Dim sFilename As String

    sFilename = "afile.xlsm:2"

    If AlreadyOpen(sFilename) Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table24").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=SearchString
    Else
        If myButton.Text = "SITE" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        ActiveWindow.NewWindow
        Windows("afile.xlsm:1").Activate
        Windows("afile.xlsm:2").Activate
        Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 55

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table24").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=SearchString
        End If
    End If
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I want Excel to open a NewWindow ("afile.xlsm:2"), Select Sheet2 and Sort Table1. But, If the second window is already open then just Sort Table24.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you want the sort to happen in Workbooks("afile.xlsm:2") whether it has to open the window or not, correct?

Comment: the sort will be in workbooks("afile.xlsm") but I need the VBA to recognize if the second window for the workbook is open. ("afile.xlsm:2")  and ("afile.xlsm:1) are the windows I'd like to be using after the second on is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Workbook` is not the same as a `Window`, which is definitely where your `If` statement is failing. You would need to modify your function to reflect that.

```
Function AlreadyOpen(sFname As String) As Boolean
    Dim wkb As Window
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wkb = Windows(sFname)
    wkb.Activate
    AlreadyOpen = Not wkb Is Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your feed back. Your edit of this Answer works nicely!

Comment: Happy to have helped!