# ActiveWindow.NewWindow Windows("aFile.xlsm:1").Activate isn't working on Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba, function, if-statement

Here was my original Question,

[How to check if "afile.xlsm:2" is already open VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153313/how-to-check-if-afile-xlsm2-is-already-open-vba)

I am building my Workbook on Excel 2013 and the above solution works. The Office has upgraded to 'Office 365'. I noticed after 'Excel 365' Opens the new window, it calls the open windows "aFile.xlsm - 1" & "aFile.xlsm - 2" compared to "aFile.xlsm:1" & "aFile.xlsm:2"

Since my Debugger is stating "Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range" on line

```
Windows("aFile.xlsm:1").Activate
```

, I tried changing my VBA Code to recognize "aFile.xlsm - 1" & "aFile.xlsm - 2" but to no prevail.

```
Function AlreadyOpen(sFname As String) As Boolean
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    'Dim sFname As String
    sFname = "aFile.xlsm:2"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wkb = Workbooks(sFname)
    AlreadyOpen = Not wkb Is Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
End Function
```

...omitted, what I think is unnecessary code related to this question.

```
Dim sFilename As String

sFilename = "aFile.xlsm:2"

If AlreadyOpen(sFilename) Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table24").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=SearchString
Else
    If myButton.Text = "SITE" Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    Windows("aFile.xlsm:1").Activate
    Windows("aFile.xlsm:2").Activate
    Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 55

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table24").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=SearchString
    End If
End If
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

How can I have this Code work on Excel 2013 and Excel 365? I'd rather not compile;

```
computername = Environ("computer name") 'Get computer name
username = Environ("user name") 'Get user name
```

into if statements.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth your while to run this while you have both windows open

```
Dim w As Window
For Each w In Application.Windows
    Debug.Print w.Caption
Next w
```

And then simply copy/paste the results from your Immediate Window into the appropriate areas of your vba code, as there may be characters you can't discern in the window title.

Additionally, if you wanted to go a more dynamic route, you could do something like

```
Dim w As Window
For Each w In Application.Windows
    If w.Caption LIKE "*aFile*2*" Then '<- the same would be used for "*aFile*1*"
        w.Activate
        Exit For
    End if
Next w
```

Would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

In O365, the Caption has changed from ":1" to "  -  1"

You can ID this by Debug.Print Activewindow.caption

You'll notice there are (2) spaces before and after the "-"